# how to solve "You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error."

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, bots, godaddy-api

I have followed this link to host .net mvc project on godadday,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/
But it shows you dont have access to resource , how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to many reasons, some of the most common are:

1. The files are uploaded to a directory the domain is not pointed towards in the cPanel setup
2. The index file has not been named appropriately (index.html , home.html, index.php. etc.) - Case sensitive
3. The DNS is not resolving to the proper host

The best way to resolve this is to contact godaddy support so that they may review the settings and configuration to ensure the initial hosting setup was configured properly.

Comment: For mine, its was reason no.2 . Thanks.